# Using GnuPG and its daemon gpg-agent

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, passwords, gnupg

I'm using `gpg-agent` to remember and supply my `GnuPG` password when building `Debian/Ubuntu` packages. But I'm still confused how `gpg-agent` works. I invoke `gpg-agent` as:

```
eval $(gpg-agent --daemon)
```

It works sometimes. But what bothers me is that sometimes it doesn't work. I.e., sometimes the building process asks for my `GnuPG` passwords once, sometimes none, and sometimes many times. This all happens during one single bash session, after I've invoked `gpg-agent` as before. Not being asked for password this time doesn't guarantee that I won't get asked for password next time. I still haven't figure out why `gpg` decides to prompt me for password and why it doesn't.

Does it happen to you as well?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to spend some time to try to pin down under what circumstances it fails and what circumstances it succeeds. If you can describe what's reliably correlated with the failure then someone else is more likely to think of a solution.

Comment: In Emacs, for GNUS and `.authinfo.gpg`, I got a hint to use `gpg2`, which `gpg-agent` is associated with. So `(setq epg-gpg-program "/usr/bin/gpg2")` worked for me. Perhaps you will have to discover which of your applications are having the issue, they may be preferring `gpg` (1).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found how to properly use `gpg-agent` from
http://tr.opensuse.org/SDB:Using_gpg-agent

Following that, my `gpg-agent` daemon is caching my `GnuPG` passwords properly now. There was nothing wrong with my setup, just that I didn't know how to test whether my `GnuPG` passwords is caching properly or not.

Now, I do:

```
echo "test" | gpg -ase -r 0xMYKEYID | gpg
```

From the site: *"Replace 0xMYKEYID with your GnuPG key ID. While running this command, the agent should open a graphical password dialog twice: first for signing or encrypting (gpg -ase)(gpg -ase) then for decryption or signature check (| gpg). From now on, every time GnuPG is used (either from the command line or embedded in a graphical program such as KMail), gpg-agent's password will be passed automatically (until the time-out expires or the graphical interface is closed)."*

And to avoid the caching expiration, I now have set extremely long timeout period:

```
$ cat ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
max-cache-ttl 60480000
default-cache-ttl 60480000
```

Comment: According to http://linux.die.net/man/1/gpg-agent, you can also add `--write-env-file "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info"` when starting gpg-agent and then add 
`if [ -f "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info" ]; then . "${HOME}/.gpg-agent-info"; export GPG_AGENT_INFO fi` 
to your .bashrc to detect whether the agent is already running. Seems like a bit cleaner solution.

Comment: @SeantheBean, excellent. I'll test it out and get back to you...

Comment: `WARNING: "--write-env-file" is an obsolete option - it has no effect` since at least `Apr 4 '16`. Ref: https://serverfault.com/a/481174